# Стиль placeholder

Tags: css3, xhtml, html, html5, css

Есть [форма](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfox/Vp82d/)

Как поменять цвет у атрибута placeholder

Comment: Наверно как-то [вот так][1]

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/Vp82d/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вам пример:

```
   /* стили для webkit */
#field2::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:#00f; }
#field3::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color:#090;
background:lightgreen;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
#field4::-webkit-input-placeholder {
font-style:italic;
text-decoration:overline;
letter-spacing:3px; color:#999;
}

/* стили для mozilla */
#field2:-moz-placeholder { color:#00f; }
#field3:-moz-placeholder {
color:#090; background:lightgreen;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
#field4:-moz-placeholder {
font-style:italic;
text-decoration:overline;
letter-spacing:3px;
color:#999;
}
```